# Write.table not separating by comma

Tags: r

Why doesn't this write out the csv as (4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4) (when viewed in Notepad)

```
results <- data.frame(Answer= rep(4,16))
write.table(results$Answer, file = "paul.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

It's as if its ignored the Sep argument..?
Paul

Comment: i think the default separator for the csv is ";"

Comment: @Guillaume.P No, that's not it. The problem is that the separator separates **columns** not rows.

Comment: how do i separate rows..?

Comment: according to write.table documentation...."the field separator string. Values within each row of x are separated by this string."

Comment: Edit your question and show me what you would expect as your csv. How many line and how many 4 per line?

Comment: I have already - I'd like to to be 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4

Comment: on one single line?

Comment: yes on one single line

Comment: I don't understand why the sep=',' isn't taking effect..?

Comment: You seem not to have noticed that your quote is, with my emphasis, "the field separator string. Values **within** each row of x are separated by this string." When you separate rows the standard character is the newline, argument `eol`. But then you will have all rows in the same line of the [text] file. Set `eol = ","`.

Comment: OK -the eol worked...thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should not define variable as one column if you want `sep` to work because `sep = ...` works with columns. This is one way you can do it:

```
results <- data.frame(t(rep(4,16)))
write.table(results, file = "paul.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple possibilities.
One, use argument `eol = ","` like I have said in my comment above. The problem with this method is that it will include an extra `","` at the end of the line, since `write.table` always includes an ending newline.

```
write.table(results$Answer, file = "paul.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, eol = ",")
```

The other method is to use `cat`.

```
cat(results$Answer, file = "paul.csv", sep = ",")
```

I believe this is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a vertical vector. When a vertical vector is being written, each vector element is written into an own line:

```
> results <- data.frame(Answer= rep(4,16))
> dim(results)
[1] 16  1
> results
   Answer
1       4
2       4
3       4
4       4
5       4
6       4
7       4
8       4
9       4
10      4
11      4
12      4
13      4
14      4
15      4
16      4
```

If you want to write the vector in a single line, you may transpose a vertical vector into a horizontal vector using function `t( )`:

```
> results <- t(data.frame(Answer= rep(4,16)))
> dim(results)
[1]  1 16
> results
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
Answer    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
```

Then writing the data into a file:

```
> results <- t(data.frame(Answer= rep(4,16)))
> write.table(results$Answer, file = "paul.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

will yield the following contents:

```
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
```

Comment: Sorry, but if you transpose a df the result is of class `matrix` and `results$Answer` throws an error. It must be `results["Answer", ]`.